# If stored procedure return no results do not send email

Tags: html, sql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in order to receive results of a "select" as HTML table via email and created a job. Job has only one step which executes my SP.

When "select" returns no result, I receive blank email however I don't want to receive any emails when "select" returns no result.

How can I do that; in select, SP, job?

Thank you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTEST]
AS
   DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
   DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
    SET @xml = CAST((SELECT 
                        A as 'td','',
                        B as 'td','',
                        C as 'td','',
                        D as 'td','',
                        E as 'td'
                     FROM           
                        ......
                     WHERE 
                        .......   
                     FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

    SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Test</H3>
                <table border = 1> 
                <tr>
                <th> A </th> <th> B </th> <th> C <th> D </th> <th> E </th>
                </tr>'    

    SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @profile_name = 'TestProfile',
           @body = @body,
           @body_format ='HTML',
           @importance = 'High',
           @recipients = '......',
           @subject = '......'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are no rows, the `@xml` variable would be NULL, based on this NULL value, you can return with out sending the mail.

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX) =NULL
SET @xml = CAST((
....
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))  

IF ( @xml is NULL ) return
```